# Can't get directions from GoogleMaps because of "found nil" unrapping URL

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, maps, directions

I searched through this topic and found some codes I tried to implement into my project, but it won't work!

So, what do I wanna achieve? 
I wanna have a button in the UI, and when user tap the button, the app displays directions to a specific point on the GoogleMap. But my function crashes on the URL.

This is my code:

```
func draw(src: CLLocationCoordinate2D, dst: CLLocationCoordinate2D){

    let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(src)&destination=\(dst)&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=**API_KEY**" <- // Here I place API-Key

    let url = URL(string: urlString)  // Here is the crash!

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                let routes = json["routes"] as! NSArray
                self.mapView.clear()

                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                    for route in routes
                    {
                        let routeOverviewPolyline:NSDictionary = (route as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "overview_polyline") as! NSDictionary
                        let points = routeOverviewPolyline.object(forKey: "points")
                        let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points! as! String)
                        let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                        polyline.strokeWidth = 3

                        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
                        self.mapView!.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 30.0))

                        polyline.map = self.mapView

                    }
                })
            }catch let error as NSError{
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

I don't know if the problem could be with the API-key, or if there's something else. I read that spaces etc could cause this issue, but I can't find what's wrong!

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2019-06-14 16:50:45 Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly create `urlString` with directly using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` as you have to use it's properties `latitude`/`longitude`

```
let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(src)&destination=\(dst)&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=**API_KEY**" <- // Here I place API-Key
```

it should be

```
let urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(src.latitude),\(src.longitude)&destination=\(dst.latitude),\(dst.longitude)&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=**API_KEY**" <- // Here I place API-Key
```

Also it's better to avoid `!` and do

```
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSThreadException', reason: 'The API method must be called from the main thread'

Comment: `self.mapView.clear()` should be inside main operation also

Comment: I put it inside OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ , and no error/exception! But it won't draw polyline on map.

Comment: make sure to set the mapView delegate and implement all needed methods

Comment: the routes is empty, I can't see why! That's the problem, "json["routes"] as! NSArray causes error/empty. How can I solve this?